# SQL Query to show order of work orders

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

First off sorry for the poor subject line.

EDIT: The Query here duplicates OrderNumbers I am needing the query to NOT duplicate OrderNumbers 
EDIT: Shortened the question and provided a much cleaner question

I have a table that has a record of all of the work orders that have been performed. there are two types of orders. Installs and Trouble Calls. My query is to find all of the trouble calls that have taken place within 30 days of an install and match that trouble call (TC) to the proper Install (IN). So the Trouble Call date has to happen after the install but no more than 30 days after. Additionally if there are two installs and two trouble calls for the same account all within 30 days and they happen in order the results have to reflect that. The problem I am having is I am getting an Install order matching to two different Trouble Calls (TC) and a Trouble Call(TC) that is matching to two different Installs(IN)

In the example on SQL Fiddle pay close attention to the install order number 1234567810 and the Trouble Call order number 1234567890 and you will see the issue I am having.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/811df/8

```
select b.accountnumber,
       MAX(b.scheduleddate) as OriginalDate,
       b.workordernumber as OriginalOrder,
       b.jobtype as OriginalType,
       MIN(a.scheduleddate) as NewDate,
       a.workordernumber as NewOrder,
       a.jobtype as NewType 
from (
      select workordernumber,accountnumber,jobtype,scheduleddate 
      from workorders 
      where jobtype = 'TC'
     ) a join 
     (
       select workordernumber,accountnumber,jobtype,scheduleddate 
       from workorders  
       where jobtype = 'IN'
     ) b
on a.accountnumber = b.accountnumber 
group by b.accountnumber,
         b.scheduleddate,
         b.workordernumber,
         b.jobtype, 
         a.accountnumber,
         a.scheduleddate,
         a.workordernumber,
         a.jobtype
having MIN(a.scheduleddate) > MAX(b.scheduleddate) and 
      DATEDIFF(day,MAX(b.scheduleddate),MIN(a.scheduleddate)) < 31
```

Example of what I am looking for the results to look like. 
Thank you for any assistance you can provide in setting me on the correct path. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You were actually very close. I realized that what you really want is the `MIN()` TC date that is greater than each install date for that account number so long as they are 30 days or less apart.

So really you need to group by the install dates from your result set excluding `WorkOrderNumber`s still. Something like:

```
SELECT a.AccountNumber, MIN(a.scheduleddate) TCDate, b.scheduleddate INDate
FROM 
    (
        SELECT WorkOrderNumber, ScheduledDate, JobType, AccountNumber
        FROM workorders
        WHERE JobType = 'TC'
    ) a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT WorkOrderNumber, ScheduledDate, JobType, AccountNumber
        FROM workorders
        WHERE JobType = 'IN'
    ) b
    ON a.AccountNumber = b.AccountNumber
WHERE b.ScheduledDate < a.ScheduledDate
    AND DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ScheduledDate, a.ScheduledDate) <= 30
GROUP BY a.AccountNumber, b.AccountNumber, b.ScheduledDate
```

This takes care of the dates and `AccountNumber`s, but you still need the `WorkOrderNumber`s, so I joined the `workorders` table back twice, once for each type.

NOTE: I assume that each workorder has a unique date for each account number.  So, if you have workorder 1 ('TC') for account 1 done on '1/1/2015' and you also have workorder 2 ('TC') for account 1 done on '1/1/2015' then I can't guarantee that you will have the correct `WorkOrderNumber` in your result set.

My final query looked like this:

```
SELECT 
    aggdata.AccountNumber, inst.workordernumber OriginalWorkOrderNumber, inst.JobType OriginalJobType, inst.ScheduledDate OriginalScheduledDate,
    tc.WorkOrderNumber NewWorkOrderNumber, tc.JobType NewJobType, tc.ScheduledDate NewScheduledDate
FROM (
        SELECT a.AccountNumber, MIN(a.scheduleddate) TCDate, b.scheduleddate INDate
        FROM 
            (
                SELECT WorkOrderNumber, ScheduledDate, JobType, AccountNumber
                FROM workorders
                WHERE JobType = 'TC'
            ) a
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT WorkOrderNumber, ScheduledDate, JobType, AccountNumber
                FROM workorders
                WHERE JobType = 'IN'
            ) b
            ON a.AccountNumber = b.AccountNumber
        WHERE b.ScheduledDate < a.ScheduledDate
            AND DATEDIFF(DAY, b.ScheduledDate, a.ScheduledDate) <= 30
        GROUP BY a.AccountNumber, b.AccountNumber, b.ScheduledDate
    ) aggdata
    LEFT OUTER JOIN workorders tc
    ON aggdata.TCDate = tc.ScheduledDate
        AND aggdata.AccountNumber = tc.AccountNumber
        AND tc.JobType = 'TC'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN workorders inst
    ON aggdata.INDate = inst.ScheduledDate
        AND aggdata.AccountNumber = inst.AccountNumber
        AND inst.JobType = 'IN'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select in1.accountnumber,
       in1.scheduleddate as OriginalDate,
       in1.workordernumber as OriginalOrder,
       'IN' as OriginalType,
       tc.scheduleddate as NewDate,
       tc.workordernumber as NewOrder,
       'TC' as NewType 
from 
      workorders in1
      out apply   (Select min(in2.scheduleddate) as scheduleddate  from workorders in2 Where  in2.jobtype = 'IN' and in1.accountnumber=in2.accountnumber and in2.scheduleddate>in1.scheduleddate) ins
      join workorders tc on tc.jobtype = 'TC' and tc.accountnumber=in1.accountnumber and tc.scheduleddate>in1.scheduleddate and (ins.scheduleddate is null or tc.scheduleddate<ins.scheduleddate) and DATEDIFF(day,in1.scheduleddate,tc.scheduleddate) < 31
        Where     in1.jobtype = 'IN'
```

Comment: please consider adding an explanation why your answer is correct